# what to do with functions documentations

Tags: javascript, php, sublimetext3

I am very unfamiliar with functions documentations on SublimeText 3

```
/**
 * gets all the groups that a user is involved in
 * @param  [int] user_id the user id
 * @return [array] returns an array of groups
 */
function get_user_groups($user_id){
```

I thought by writing my function documentation following this syntax, I would get a sort of a tooltip containing the above description as soon as I hover the function name somewhere else in the code. 
example:

[image]

Is there anyway to get that working or do I need an extension for it?
I am not sure I know what I am talking about, I used to have this feature on visual studio when I was working with typescript. Please advise.

Comment: are you asking how to get the notes when you hover over the function when it's being used?

Comment: that's correct .

Comment: in that case ...  not sure tbh, PHPStorm doesn't do this, nor would I expect it to I guess ... are you not able to `CTRL + LEFT-CLICK` the function to "jump" to the function declaration?

Comment: Eclipse shows this tooltip. I think any IDE will show it. google results for [this package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ToolTip-Helper) for sublimetext.

Comment: I can, by pressing F12 however

Comment: @treyBake In PHPStorm, click the cursor onto a function call and press `Ctrl + Q` to view functions' annotations.

Comment: @GaryThomas ah nevermind, must have missed my cursor on it. Working - though I prefer ye olde CTRL + CLICK xD

Comment: I need this for sublime text

Comment: Out of the box Sublime only supports symbol definitions and references, not documentation tooltips or usage popups. To get that sort of functionality you need to install a third party package that reads and processes your code for you. An example of that is [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) (which also requires you to install an external LSP server for the language you're using).